# Silverlight vs. ASP when targetting thin clients

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, performance, thin-client

I'm actually looking for an opinion here. At work, we were discussing the downfalls of creating some of our applications in silverlight as they will be used via thinclient and since silverlight runs client side, there was concern for performance. Now, these apps aren't going to be rich by any means, mostly data entry forms and account management type stuff; so I'm wondering should there really be any concern for it?

Any thoughts?

Comment: "...mostly data entry forms...Any thoughts?" - HTML 5!  You seem to be saying you are worried about performance in an area where you don't need to be worried by performance.

Comment: This appears to suit [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) better. In fact, there are already some discussions on this. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/86983, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/30031, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/10334, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/70903, [more](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=silverlight).

Comment: @MitchWheat the company will not allow anything unsupported by IE

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would go ASP.Net silverlight does not appear to have a very sure future.

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/will-there-be-a-silverlight-6-and-does-it-matter/11180

This means that you could have a hard time finding devs to work on it in the future / or it will cost more to hire them.

This also means you could be working in a obsolete technology 6 months into a project. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Linking to my opinion about Silverlight - http://pradeepgururani.blogspot.in/2011/10/death-of-silverlight.html

Answer (score -1):

What's the problem with good ol' html? Maybe a CLI data entry app?
The last thing you want when dealing with "microsoft only" companies is playing along. Do you get extra pay for using a technology? If not, don't add an extra layer to your system, be it Adobe's or Microsoft's or whoever. Also, don't jump into the magical html 5 wagon of joy,it's just no there yet.